# Spark ml and PMML export

Tags: java, apache-spark, linear-regression, pmml

I know that it's possible to export models as `PMML` with `Spark-MLlib`, but what about `Spark-ML`?

Is it possible to convert `LinearRegressionModel` from `org.apache.spark.ml.regression` to a `LinearRegressionModel` from `org.apache.spark.mllib.regression` to be able to invoke the `toPMML()` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can convert Spark ML pipelines to PMML using the [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library:

```
StructType schema = dataFrame.schema()
PipelineModel pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(dataFrame);
org.dmg.pmml.PMML pmml = org.jpmml.sparkml.ConverterUtil.toPMML(schema, pipelineModel);
JAXBUtil.marshalPMML(pmml, new StreamResult(System.out));
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it asap